# Unpacking parameter pack of args into the constructor of each class defined in a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a class that inherits from multiple classes (as defined by a variadic template) and, for each class, passes the same parameter pack of args to the constructor of each class. However, it seems as though I'm not able to unpack both the variadic template of classes and the parameter pack of args.

I have a class:

```
template<class... __Policies>
class GenericPolicyAdapter : public __Policies...{
```

With constructor:

```
template<class... __Args>
GenericPolicyAdapter( __Args... args ) : __Policies( args... ){
```

and test:

```
GenericPolicyAdapter<T1,T2> generic_policy_adapter( arg1, arg2, arg3 );
```

gcc fails with:

```
error: type ‘__Policies’ is not a direct base of ‘GenericPolicyAdapter<T1,T2>’
```

where `__Policies = T1, T2`

To clarify, I'm essentially trying to do:

```
GenericPolicyAdapter : public T1, public T2
{
  public:
    template<class... __Args>
    GenericPolicyAdapter( __Args... args ) : T1( args... ), T2( args... ){}
};
```

but with `T1` and `T2` deduced from `__Policies`

Any ideas? It seems like gcc is treating `__Policies` as a single type rather than a list of types. Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

I should clarify that I'm using gcc/g++ 4.4.5.

The suggestion by Howard Hinnant was to do:

```
template<class... __Args>
    GenericPolicyAdapter( __Args... args )
        : __Policies( args...)...
    {}
```

However, with gcc/g++ 4.4.5, this gives `invalid use of pack expansion expression`. It's great that this works in OSX/clang but is there a way to do this in gcc/g++?

Comment: Please note that 4.4 is ancient in regards to C++11 support and that even in 4.6 variadic template support, especially the unpacking of parameter packs is incomplete.

Comment: Don't even bother trying to use anything older than gcc 4.7 (4.8 even better) if you're really interested in C++11

Comment: Also note that you should not use identifiers starting with `__` or `_<UPPERCASE>` in your code. These patterns are reserved for the compiler and its standard library. A new version of your compiler might introduce a `#define __Args` without warning, breaking your code.

Answer (score 16):

"`...`" is a lot like "`typename`".  You just have to keep aggressively sprinkling it around until things compile. :-)

```
template<class... __Policies>
class GenericPolicyAdapter
    : public __Policies...
{
public:
    template<class... __Args>
        GenericPolicyAdapter( __Args... args )
            : __Policies( args...)...
        {}
};

struct T1
{
    T1(int, int, int) {}
};

struct T2
{
    T2(int, int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
    GenericPolicyAdapter<T1,T2> generic_policy_adapter( 1, 2, 3 );
}
```

Comment: Strange, I get tons of `error: invalid use of pack expansion expression` in GCC 4.6.1. I was trying something like this myself, but with no success.

Comment: I was curious if gcc would swallow this.  I don't have the expertise to claim that clang is correct.  However I can say that the lead author on the variadic template proposal is also the lead contributor to clang for variadic templates (Doug Gregor).

Comment: Tried that before I posted; gcc 4.4.5 would have none of it :(

"Invalid use of pack expansion expression"

Comment: Looks like we need an authoritative answer on nested, multiple pack expansions. If we can't get one soon, I'll put up some bounty.

Comment: I asked Doug to take a look at this solution and he says it is correct, and accepted by both clang and EDG.  [temp.variadic]/p4/b4 specifies that base-specifier-list can contain a pack expansion (as in this example), and [temp.variadic]/p5 describes the behavior of nested pack expansions.  And if I messed this explanation up too badly, Doug will tell me and I'll correct it! :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I would interpret the standard in the same way (that the above is correctly accepted by clang). As stated in the comment to the post, gcc is still very weak on variadic template support, especially when it comes to expansion of parameter packs (e.g. it cant unpack them into fixed lists), probably because when it was implemented in 4.3/4.4 it was following a very early, incomplete proposal. Even the svn version is weak on this example.

Comment: I didn't include it because I didn't want to complicate the answer.  But yes, if I were coding this for myself I would `: Policies( std::forward<Args>(args)...)...`.  Additionally I would not precede everything with underscores unless I was working as the C++ vendor.

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

> 14.5.3 Variadic templates                                 [temp.variadic]
>
> 5       A parameter pack whose name appears within the pattern of a pack expansion is expanded by that pack expansion. **An appearance of the name of a parameter pack is only expanded by the innermost enclosing pack expansion. The pattern of a pack expansion shall name one or more parameter packs that are not expanded by a nested pack expansion.** All of the parameter packs expanded by a pack expansion shall have the same number of arguments specified. An appearance of a name of a parameter pack that is not expanded is ill-formed. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<typename...> struct Tuple {};
> template<typename T1, typename T2> struct Pair {};
>
> template<class ... Args1> struct zip {
>   template<class ... Args2> struct with {
>     typedef Tuple<Pair<Args1, Args2> ... > type;
>   };
> };
>
> typedef zip<short, int>::with<unsigned short, unsigned>::type T1;
>     // T1 is Tuple<Pair<short, unsigned short>, Pair<int, unsigned>>
> typedef zip<short>::with<unsigned short, unsigned>::type T2;
>     // error: different number of arguments specified for Args1 and Args2
>
> template<class ... Args> void g(Args ... args) {
>   f(const_cast<const Args*>(&args)...); // OK: “Args” and “args” are expanded
>   f(5 ...); // error: pattern does not contain any parameter packs
>   f(args); // error: parameter pack “args” is not expanded
>   f(h(args ...) + args ...); // OK: first “args” expanded within h, second
>   // “args” expanded within f
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]

I think that `f(h(args ...) + args ...);` might be the closest standardese example you will get.

Note that if you had done:

```
template<class... __Policies>
class GenericPolicyAdapter
    : public __Policies...
{
public:
    template<class... __Args>
        GenericPolicyAdapter( __Args... args )
            : __Policies(args)... // See the missing '...' ?
        {}
};
```

You would have pulled a single arg of the constructor parameter list, and applied them in order to the base constructors.  The key is to expand `__Policies` after you expand `args`.

Comment: What happens when you have multiple, separate parameter packs around, though?

Comment: The pattern of a pack expansion shall name **one or more parameter packs** that are not expanded by a nested pack expansion.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in a  comment, gcc is pretty weak on variadic template support to day. Especially when it comes to parameter pack expansions. Gcc 4.6 can not even expand packs into fixed length lists.

The following code is a possible workaround that is based on a far more complex way of working around those limitations that I usually use. It will only compile on a very recent gcc from svn:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct derive : T
{
    template<class... A>
    derive( A... a ) :
        T(a...)
    {
    }
};

template<class X, class... T>
struct deriver;

template<class X>
struct deriver<X> :
    derive<X>
{
    template<class... A>
    deriver( A... a ) :
        derive<X>(a...)
    {
    }
};

template<class X, class... T>
struct deriver : 
    derive<X>, deriver<T...>
{
    template<class... A>
    deriver( A... a ) :
        derive<X>(a...), deriver<T...>(a...)
    {
    }
};

template<class... __Policies>
class GenericPolicyAdapter
    : public deriver<__Policies...>
{
public:
    template<class... __Args>
        GenericPolicyAdapter( __Args... args )
            : deriver<__Policies...>( args...)
        {}
};

#define BARK std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"
struct T1
{
    T1(int, int, int) {BARK;}
};

struct T2
{
    T2(int, int, int) {BARK;}
};

int main()
{
    GenericPolicyAdapter<T1,T2> generic_policy_adapter( 1, 2, 3 );
}
```

All released gccs will choke on this with:

```
sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'T ...' into a fixed-length argument list
```

which can possibly also worked around by even more indirection, but this should be a good starting point (depending on how much portability you want).